# Call to a member function getAssociationAdmin() on null

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In my admin class, I have a one to many field used as CollectionType.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
            ->add('title', null, ['required' => true])
            ->add('options', CollectionType::class, [], [
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
             ]);
}
```

In Sonata create form, it works fine when **Add new** is clicked. But I need to customize form fields based on create and edit. So when I altered my code as,

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    if ($this->isCurrentRoute('create')) {
        $formMapper
            ->add('title', null, ['required' => true])
            ->add('options', CollectionType::class, [], [
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
             ]);
    }

    if ($this->isCurrentRoute('edit')) {
        $formMapper
            ->add('title', null, ['disabled' => true])
            ->add('options', CollectionType::class, [], [
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
             ]);
    }
}
```

**Add new** is not working in create form. It throws **Call to a member function getAssociationAdmin() on null** error for method named **append-form-field-element?code=admin...** found in network debug in browser.

My question here is, **Add new** button for one to many collection type works when $formMapper is common for both create and edit but doesn't work when $formMapper is customized for create and edit form.

Does anyone have suggestion or solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is, that your Admin is embedded somewhere else in your project. The parent admin is calling your configureformFields method in your child admin but is not serving the currentRoute information for it. So it will not hit any of your two cases and the form is not configured and ends up in that error. Could you check if your form is embedded somewhere else in your application?

Comment: No, it is not embedded else where. All fields except that CollectionType are working fine.